# R can not interpret big numbers correctly

Tags: r

In R language, I have a problem regarding the big integers.
I type the number in the console, but the response is not equal to my input.

```
7241562255469626002  
[1] 7241562255469626368
```

I also tried to set the digits option but it did not work:

```
options("digits" = 22)  
7241562255469626002  
[1] 7241562255469626368
```

What should I do to make it interpret the big numbers correctly?